# MariaDB Remove text from record

Tags: mariadb, record, longtext

I have longtext data in data column as show by image, how to remove

```
{"current_id_position":"8861","targetted_id_position":"","count_new_technical":"0"}
```

for all record in 1 query? I just need number inside targetted_id_position

[image]

Thanks, hope u're helping me. I'm so confused what should I do.

Comment: Please tag your question correctly in the future. MariaDB and MySQL are different products. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, but both products have been changing since then. In particular, the JSON features were developed independently in each product, and are not fully compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the column contains JSON, you can use the [JSON extraction operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-inline-path).

```
UPDATE tableName
SET data = data->>'$.targetted_id_position'
```

MariaDB didn't copy MySQL's `->>` operator, so you have to call the functions instead.

```
UPDATE tableName
SET data = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.targetted_id_position'))
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. I tried that code you give but it show an error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '>>'*.targetted_id_position'' at line 2

Error show like that

Comment: MariaDB doesn't have MySQL's shorthand operators for JSON_EXTRACT. I've updated the answer.

Comment: That code is works but number inside targetted_id_position is gone and now all record is null

Comment: Sorry, `*` was supposed to be `$`.